# How to center images horizontally?

Tags: css

I'm trying to center images in a container but it is not working. Til sofar the css looks like this;

```
#wrap{
min-height: 100%;
}
#imagebar{
 position:fixed;
 margin:0 auto;
 top:60%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
}
#albums{
margin:8px;
    display: inline-block;              
}
```

My website is http://www.robcnossen.nl/

I thought that margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; would  be good but thinks are not working how I thought it would be.
Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks...

Comment: Are you trying to center the bar or the images? `margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;` won't work in this case because your position is fixed.

Comment: the images in your link are centered in the page?

Answer (score 3):

```
#imagebar {text-align:center;}
```

Your images aren't block-level elements, so simply applying `text-align:center;` to their parent will do the trick.

Comment: I am puzzling on this this hole day and the answer is one simple line. Thank you very much...

Comment: No prbblem, feel free to mark as the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `#imagebar` has a width of 100%, its automaticly centered. You can center the images by using `text-align: center` within `#imagebar`.

I however think you want a specific 'content box' within `#imagebar` that is centered.

You can fix that by making a div inside `#imagebar` with a fix width (in px or %) and add `margin: 0 auto` to that inner div.